# Yii2 Pjax Gridview in Modal will reload page instead of updating

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, modal-dialog, pjax

I had a problem with Pjax, actually on somepage I load a view in Modal, and in this modal I use GridView with filter option with selectbox. When user changes the filter, the content will not be updated, but the page will be redirected to the filtered URL (Gridview with data updated).

When the view is working outside the modal it works fine, and update its contents!

Here is my code:

index.php, here I load my modal:

```
<div>

<?php
Modal::begin([
'header' => '',
'id' => 'modal-window',
'class' => 'modal',        
'footer' => '<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>',
    'clientOptions' => ['backdrop' => false]
]);

Modal::end();
?>
```

And in view:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax_translation','enablePushState' => false, 'timeout' => false,]); ?>
<div class="row">
<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>   
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel'  => $searchModel,
    'filterUrl'    => Url::to(["translate/view" , "id" => $id ]),
    'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered translate-list',"style"=> ""],           
    'options' => ['data-pjax' => true ],
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'language',
            'filter' => $arrLanguage,
            'content'=>  function($model) use ($arrLanguage){
                return isset($arrLanguage[$model->language])? $arrLanguage[$model->language] : "" ;  
             },                
            'headerOptions' => ['width' => '150'],
        ],
        [
            
            'attribute' => 'translation',                
            
        ],                                                
    ],      
]); ?>
</div>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

And in my controller the code is:

```
public function actionView($id)
{        
    $view = "view";
    
    $searchModel = new TranslateMessageSearch();
    
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProvider->query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $id,            
    ]);
    
    
     if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {            
        \Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';

        $html = $this->renderAjax($view, [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'id'=>$id,
        ]);
        
        return ['success' => true, 'html' => $html] ;
        
    } else {
        return $this->render($view, [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'id'=>$id,
        ]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: how do you "load a view in Modal"? is your example complete? i think your Pjax block belongs into the modal's body

Comment: yes, my pjax block belongs into modals body, but now i found the solution i will post it down here.

Answer (score 0):

i found finally a solution after three days testing everything. I will post it here, maybe it could be usefull for someone who has the same problem.
I just put in my view.php the following js at the top:

```
$js = "$(document).on('submit', 'form[data-pjax]', function(event) {
    $.pjax.submit(event, '#pjax_translation', {
        'push': false,
        'replace': false,
        'timeout': 5000,
        'scrollTo': false,
        'maxCacheLength': 0
    });             
});";     
$this->registerJs($js);
```

and everything is work fine now :)

Comment: i configured that loading a pjax into modal box will not trigger pjax on the submit form when the main page is already loaded, so i though maybe i should reassign the event to pjax again after fulling the modals body, but here i put the triggering code inside the view itself, und not inside js modals functions

Comment: did you try putting your submit button within Pjax? i think you don't need to  use JS for this.

Comment: i do not have an explicit form within my code, i think the form comes from Gridview filter, even i did not find it in the html source

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me:

```
<?php Modal::begin([
    'header'        => '',
    'id'            => 'modal-window',
    'class'         => 'modal',        
    'toggleButton'  => ['label' => 'click me'],
    'footer'        => '<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>',
    'clientOptions' => ['backdrop' => false]
]); ?>

    <?php Pjax::begin() ?>
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['data-pjax' => 1]]) ?>
            <?= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()) ?> <button type="submit">click this</button>
        <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
    <?php Pjax::end() ?>

<?php Modal::end(); ?>
```

PS: Maybe your page gets reloaded because you hit [Pjax timeout](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-pjax#$timeout-detail)